# Separating line of linear gradient at bottom left corner

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I want the separating line between two colors of a linear gradient always to start at the bottom left corner.

[image]

This example is hard-coded and if I resize the window it does not work anymore. The rotation should stay the same. So the percentage value of the colors should change.

```
linear-gradient(172deg, #0000ff 69%, #ff0000 69%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like below with multiple background:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%, red 50%) left bottom /
    2000px /* Keep this always big to have the same angle*/ 
    300px  /* adjust this to control the angle. angle = acrtan(300/2000) */
    no-repeat,
    blue;
}
```

Comment: Works almost perfectly. But if I insert a picture instead of blue and set its size to cover, it no longer works and the separating line goes from the bottom left corner to the top right.

Comment: @Matze you need to set cover to only the image and no both background: https://jsfiddle.net/1rayqb7k/